# AWS Cloudera Director Cluster Install Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, cluster-computing, cloudera

I am trying to spin up a cluster via `AWS Cloudera Director`. Manager installs fine however upon tailing the installation I find this error.

```
[2016-06-06 17:16:24] ERROR [pipeline-thread-31] - c.c.l.p.DatabasePipelineRunner: Pipeline '4e04f8e6-5dfc-4603-b58b-9474e054bca6' failed
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error is a high-level error. Earlier in the log should be an error indicating the root cause of the failure.